# while and foreach interaction

Tags: arrays, perl, foreach, while-loop

I am having an undesired interaction with a `foreach` loop and a `while` that I don't quite understand. I have a normal `for` loop, and then a `foreach` loop going through an array. I create a string (representing a file name) with both and then open the file and read it.

The code I use is here:

```
@array=(1,2);
for($y=0;$y<2;$y++)
{
    foreach(@array)
    {
        print "@array\n";
        $name="/Users/jorge/$_\_vs_$y\.txt";
        print "$name\n";
        open(INFILE,"$name") or die "Can't open files!\n";
        while(<INFILE>)
        {
            $line=$_;
        }
    }
}
```

and the output is:

```
array: 1 2
/Users/jorge/1_vs_0.txt
array:  2
/Users/jorge/2_vs_0.txt
array:  
/Users/jorge/_vs_1.txt
```

Seems that somehow the while loop is shortening my array, if I remove the:

```
while(<INFILE>)
```

it works as intented, also if I change the foreach too:

```
foreach $tmp (@array)
```

and use $tmp instead of $_, it also works as intended, the output looks like this:

```
array: 1 2
/Users/jorge/1_vs_0.txt
array: 1 2
/Users/jorge/2_vs_0.txt
array: 1 2
/Users/jorge/1_vs_1.txt
array: 1 2
/Users/jorge/2_vs_1.txt
array: 1 2
/Users/jorge/1_vs_2.txt
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using `$_` as the loop control variable on two nested loops. Instead, you should give each loop its own variable.

Not only is the inner loop changing the value of the control variable for the outer loop, but it's also changing the actual array being looped over.  That's because the loop control variable in Perl's `for`/`foreach` *aliases* the elements of the array, so when the `<INFILE>` construct reads a line into `$_`, it overwrites the current element of `@array` with that line. When the `while` loop finishes reading the file, `$_` comes out of the last `<INFILE>` as undefined, which means the most-recently processed element of `@array` will always be undefined when you get back to the top of the `foreach` loop.

You should also be declaring your variables with `my`, using a lexical scalar instead of a bareword as a file handle, and using the the three-argument version of `open`, so I've made those changes below as well.  But the solution to your shrinking-array problem is just the use of an explicit variable instead of the default `$_` for at least one of the two loops.

```
my @array = (1, 2);
for (my $y = 0; $y < 2; $y++)
{
  foreach my $x (@array)   # using $x instead of $_
  {
    print "@array\n";
    my $name = "/Users/jorge/${x}_vs_$y.txt";  
    print "$name\n";
    open my $infile, '<', $name or die "$0: can't open file '$name': $!\n";
    while (my $line = <$infile>)   # using $line instead of $_
    {
        # do something with $line here
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You can use [`B::Deparse`](http://perldoc.perl.org/B/Deparse.html) to demonstrate: `perl -MO=Deparse -e 'foreach(1..10) { while(<>) { } }'`

Comment: `for` and `foreach` implicitly localize `$_` so nesting them is safe (though poor form). `while` does *not* localize and will clobber the value in its enclosing scope.

Answer (score 1):

Your while loop overwrites content of array as it uses `$_` which is aliased to `@array` elements.

It is best to use lexical (my) variable when reading file using `while`,

```
    while (my $line = <INFILE>) {

        # ..
    }
```

Comment: You don't need that assignment in there. Just use `while ( my $line = <INFILE> ) {` instead.